# Xcode Mistakenly Added Library to Project and I Can't get Rid of it

Tags: xcode, reference

So I was trying to add some files to my project and double clicked on library and before I know it the whole entire library was being referenced into my project.

At first I thought, okay no big deal I'll just remove the reference, I did that it took some time, I saved afterword all seem fine, I even added some code.

From here I closed my project, come in the next day open the project and the library  is in my project indexing itself. I try removing the reference again and it seems to go away, but now some of my work from the day before isn't there however some of it is, so my program can't run. To top things off Xcode crashes, open up my project again and library is still there, can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

From the Apple Developer Website:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/configuration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012554-CH3-SW1

> Select the Build Settings tab in your application target editor. Find the “Other Linker Flags” build setting. Add the flag -ObjC to this build setting’s value if it is not already present. This flag will tell the linker to link all Objective-C classes and categories from static libraries into your application, even if the linker can’t tell that they are used. This is needed because Objective-C is a dynamic language and the linker can’t always tell which classes and categories are used by your application code.

So I recommend to see if this has been done in your project settings and if it has then delete the flag in your build settings.